# Oracle Apex 5.1 Explicitly sizing Cards and limiting Cards to one per row

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to size Cards so that there is only one card per row?  My source is a list and I am using the List Template "cards".

What I would like to ultimately do is have 2 regions that exactly share the page so that the first region is a single card and the second region is a single card.  I am looking for the cards to always be the same size regardless of the length of the text.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to an APEX 5.1 environment to test, but in the latest version of APEX, if you create a Cards region and in the region's attributes, under Appearance change the Layout to **Horizontal (Row)**, only one card will be displayed per row.

I've created a [sample on apex.oracle.com](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/adptest/r/ej-demo/card-demo).

[image]